# Better way to say "I don't have any other option besides doing it"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Is there a better way to phrase

> I don't have any other options besides going there.

And can we use words like restrain,constrained or something like them?

And if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of alternatives, but here are some:

- I don't have any option *other than* going there.
- My only option is to go there.
- I've got to go, there are no other options.

"Restrained" and "constrained" don't mean the same thing - '*restrain*' means to *prevent* from doing something, so that wouldn't really fit your context where you *must* do something. '*Constrain*' means to *limit* something, so you could say:

- My options are constrained, I must go.

Comment: Today I found one that can be used here as well: *there was nothing for it but to go there*. Well there is a slight connotation of unpleasantness in "going there".